# how to sort composite columns by column key in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

In columnfamily, composite column key is (integer, string). I have tried the following comparator_types:
`1. CompositeType(IntegerType, AsciiType)
2. CompositeType(IntegerType, BytesType)`

I am able to add rows to this columnfamily. But, when i query this columnfamily, columns are not sorted on composite key integer value.

How can i sort all the columns on column key integer? Is comparator_type fine? What's the best way to sort column keys on first part of composite key?

Comment: Cassandra supports order by only on second value of composite key....I use CQL don't know about astyanax but default property of cassandra is sorting on only second value of composite key

Comment: AFAIK, that's no true. Cassandra columns are sorted on first part of composite key, then on second and so on.

Comment: by sorting i meant order by and it is allowed on second part of composite key

Comment: So, you mean it is not possible to get columns sorted on first part (integer value in my case)?

Comment: First part of composite key is partition key and order by is possible when partition key is restricted by equal to operator. Details can be found here http://planetcassandra.org/blog/composite-keys-in-apache-cassandra/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the docs say you cannot sort all the columns on your first column key--the integer. First let's clarify terms for folks reading this: A composite column key is the Cassandra storage engine (Thrift/CLI) term for the compound primary key CQL term. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts

The Cassandra 2.0 docs say, "ORDER BY clauses can select a single column only. That column has to be the second column in a compound PRIMARY KEY." http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__querying-compound-primary-keys-and-sorting-results